# MATLAB multiple cells - manipulation (swap and convert to array)

Tags: matlab, cell, sparse-matrix

val represents a value and col_ind is the values column index in a matrix
Say we want to get these 2 arrays as the results:

```
  val=     [9 -2 9 -2 -2 9 -2]
  col_ind= [1  2 2  1  3 3  2]
```

from 2 cells  {val}   and {col_ind}

```
  {val}    = [9;-2] [-2;9;-2] [-2;9]
  {col_ind}= [1,2] [0,0,1,2,3] [0,0,0,0,0,2,3]
```

How do I get rid of the zeroes in the doubles in {col_ind} to get this

> {col_ind}= [1,2] [1,2,3] [2,3]

How can I swap the entries in each double and also make sure 
that the column indices are swapped appropriately such that I will get this:

```
  {val}    = [9;-2] [9;-2;-2] [9;-2]
  {col_ind}= [1,2]  [2,1,3]   [3,2]
```

How can the function sort be used in this case?

How do I merge the cells together to finally have this, an array of:

```
  col_ind = [1 2 2 1 3 3 2]
```

Comment: Are `val` and `col_ind` cell arrays ? What do you mean by "swap the entries in each double and also make sure that column indices are swapped" ? Are you looking to sort the individual arrays in val in a descending order and have col_ind in the same order ?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood you correctly:

```
col_ind= {[1,2], [0,0,1,2,3], [0,0,0,0,0,2,3]}; %define col_ind - note row vector
val    = {[9;-2]; [-2;9;-2]; [-2;9]}; %define val - note column vectors

for cellNum=1:length(col_ind) %loop for each cell inputted
    [val_sorted{cellNum},sortMap]=sort(val{cellNum},'descend'); %Sort val in descending order - not exactly clear from your Q!
    colInd_noZeros=col_ind{cellNum}(col_ind{cellNum}~=0); %Remove zeros from this col_ind cell (your 1st Q?)
    colInd_sorted{cellNum}=colInd_noZeros(sortMap); %re-order col_ind to match sorted val (your 2nd Q?)
end
%Now combine cells into an array, direction depends, use "vertcat" for column arrays, and "[]" for the row arrays (your 3rd Q?)
valArray=vertcat(val_sorted{:})'
col_indArray=[colInd_sorted{:}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way to do this using `sortrows` and `cellfun` without a `for loop`.

```
col_ind = {[1,2],[0,0,1,2,3],[0,0,0,0,0,2,3]}
val = {[9;-2], [-2;9;-2], [-2;9]}

col_ind = cellfun(@(x)x(x~=0),col_ind,'uni',0) % Get rid of zeros from the indices
 % Sort in descending order and split results in cells
valAndIdx = cellfun(@(x,y)mat2cell(sortrows([x y(:)],-1),numel(x),[1 1]),val,col_ind,'uni',0)

tmp = (valAndIdx{:})
valArray = tmp(:,1)
col_indArray = tmp(:,2)
```